# Can't understand this Athena create table error

Tags: amazon-athena

Is there a better way to error check my create table statement below, Athena keeps giving me the useless error,

```
line 1:8: no viable alternative at input 'create external' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception;)
```

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database_1.table_1(
  `id` string,  
  `starttime` string, 
  `endtime` string, 
  `projectedflow` int, 
  `volume` int, 
  `occupancy` int, 
  `averagespeed` int, 
  `maxlaneoccupancy` int, 
  `minlaneaveragespeed` int, 
  `maxflow` int, 
  `sustainableflow` int, 
  `site_id` int as SPLIT(id, ':')[1], 
  `region` string as SPLIT(id, ':')[3], 
  `starthour` int as SPLIT(SPLIT(starttime, 'T')[2], ':')[1], 
  `startminute` int as SPLIT(SPLIT(starttime, 'T')[2], ':')[2], 
  `starttime_adj` date as CONCAT(SPLIT(starttime, 'T')[1], ' ', SPLIT(SPLIT(starttime, 'T')[2], 'Z')[1]), 
  `endtime_adj` date as CONCAT(SPLIT(endtime, 'T')[1], ' ', SPLIT(SPLIT(endtime, 'T')[2], 'Z')[1])
  )
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` int, 
  `month` int, 
  `day` int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket_1/traffic/v1/ds/csv'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'areColumnsQuoted'='false', 
  'classification'='csv', 
  'columnsOrdered'='true', 
  'compressionType'='gzip', 
  'delimiter'=',', 
  'skip.header.line.count'='4');
```

Any suggestions for strategies would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your table name contains a number `table_1`, enclose it with double quotes like `"table_1"`.

Refer here for [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html) documentation.